# Filling a rectangle in Java

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

I did some heavy googling on how to fill a rectangle using graphics2D.

I currently want to make the German flag, so three rectangles. But right now I want to just fill one rectangle and see how that goes.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class germanflag
{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        // Construct flag
        Rectangle flag = new Rectangle(0, 0, 120, 60); 

        Graphics2D g2d = flag;
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2d.fillRect(0,0,120,60);
        // draw the rectangle
        g2.draw(flag); 

    }
}
```

Obviously an error is coming up. I just don't know how to rectify it. Should the rectangle be created as I do the filling, or should it be initialized beforehand, as in this code?

Comment: Perhaps you should have a look at [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/), [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Comment: @Mad I will, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is you are trying to cast/assign instance/object of type `Rectangle` to `Grapichs2D`.

```
//Graphics2D g2d = flag; //not required
g2d.setColor(Color.RED); //use g2 instead
g2d.fillRect(0,0,120,60);//use g2 instead
```

P.S. the class `germanflag` doesn't extends any Swing component. You might be possibly looking for `JComponent` or `JPanel`.

Comment: Color is not defined. I copied that from another stackoverflow question. How can I define the color red?

Comment: @user000001 `import java.awt.Color`; perhaps you should try reading some of the tutorials instead, try starting with [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)

Comment: @Mad thanks. I keep forgetting to import every single method that i need.